# Use VPN to make upload better

Tags: speed, openvpn, upload

Today I found a couple of video on youtube that showing how to upload videos faster on youtube, by using PrivateTunnel a technology based (i think) on OpenVPN.

How can improve the upload speed? It uses packet compression?

Since PrivateTunnel is not free and i have a gigabit server, can i use my server to set up a OpenVPN like PrivateTunnel and improve the upload speed on my connection?
If yes, what features i must turn on my server config?

Video (in italian): http://youtu.be/8F8_regeCFU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Today I found a couple of video on youtube that showing how to upload
>   videos faster on youtube, by using PrivateTunnel a technology based
>   (i think) on OpenVPN.
>
> How can improve the upload speed? It uses packet compression?

I don't think that is feasible, because video formats are *already* compressed. Using a compressed connection would probably *increase* the overall data size and slow down the connection.

What a VPN could do is supply a "detour" around some bottleneck in the connection between you and YouTube. Also, of course, the VPN connection content can't be inspected, and neither can the destination port. So, traffic going through a VPN is likely to be considered "high priority" traffic by most firewalls and bandwidth sharing system, while traffic coming from ports 80/443 could be assigned a lower priority. This might be another source of "speedup" in some contexts.

(And of course in some circumstances without a VPN you might not be allowed to connect to YouTube *at all*: in those cases, the VPN guarantees an *infinite* speedup - and possibly a chance of being laid off for network use policy violations).

Finally, it is possible that some (small) optimizations *could* be performed at the network level. But unless I'm mistaken, no more than that.

Regarding your server, you need first of all to verify the upload speed between the server and YouTube. This might be considerable, since servers are usually optimized for *outgoing* data. By the same token, you also should verify the upload speed towards your server.

If, say, the server can send data to YouTube at 5 Mb/s, and you can upload data to the server at 2 Mb/s, it is conceivable that an OpenVPN setup might allow you to upload to YouTube at a bit less than 2 Mb/s. If, on the other hand, you only have 500 kb/s towards your server and 600 kb/s towards YouTube, there's little sense in even trying.

Comment: And if a video is not compressed? Well, in my case, my server is 1Gbit down/up and I have a 10/1mbit down/up.

Also, the compression can be used to speed up UDP packets, for example for minecraft server? (a popular voxel-based game)

Comment: If the video is not compressed, then the potential advantage is huge (uncompressed video can yield a 5x-10x compression when using VPN deflation). But it would be *way* better to use a specific video-oriented codec: in optimal conditions, ratios of 100:1 are achievable. Also, for this very reason, uncompressed videos aren't really diffused. For gaming, you need to take *latency* into account, perhaps more even than packet size. My guess is that the compression wouldn't be too good (packets are small and UDP is not streamed), but depending on network conditions, latency *might* benefit.